# I'm making an dependent drop-down of countries states and cities in Laravel 9 using jQuery and Ajax but getting an 500 internal server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-9, internal-server-error

I'm making an dependent drop-downn of countries states and cities in laravel using jQuery and Ajax. I'm doing it on localhost Xampp. First i use jQuery for country. when country change jQuery get value and send to Controller. But when i send value from RegistrationFormComponent to CountryStateCity Controller and try to show what value i get. I got an error ( POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/getstate 500 (Internal Server Error) ). i don't know why im getting this error.

Route:

```
Route::get('/register', [CountryStateCityController::class, 'getcountry']);
Route::POST('/getstate ', [CountryStateCityController::class, 'getstate']);
```

JQuery and Ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#country').change(function () {
    var cid = this.value;   //$(this).val(); we cal also write this.
    $.ajax({
      url: "getstate",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json",
      data: {
        country_id: cid,
      },
      success: function(result) {
        // if(cid == "success")
        //   alert(response);
          console.log(result);
      },
      errror: function(xhr) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Controller

```
class CountryStateCityController extends Controller
{
    public function getcountry() {
        $country = DB::table('countries')->get();
        $data = compact('country');
        return view('RegistrationForm')->with($data);
    }

    public function getstate(Request $request) {
        
        $state = State::where('countryid'->$cid)->get();
        return response()->json($state);
    }

    public function getcity() {
    }
}
```

I think i tryed every possible thing. But didn't work. Please tell me how can i get rid of this problem. And please also tell me how can i send data from component to controller using jquery and ajax and get value form controller and take data from database and send back to component.

Comment: You need @csrf in your form and possible a csrf meta tag in your head. Your post should be sending the csrf token to make the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is written incorrectly.

```
public function getstate(Request $request) {
        
        $state = State::where('countryid'->$cid)->get();
        return response()->json($state);
    }
```

It should look like this.

```
public function getstate(Request $request) {
        
        $state = State::where('countryid', '=', $request->country_id)->get();
        return response()->json($state);
    }
```

Comment: ( ‘=‘, ) This is making an error.

Comment: if you copied it from my post I noticed the quotes were not right. they are correct now.

Comment: I found another issue. $request->$cid is supposed to be $request->country_id

Comment: Thank You. it worked but also include ( $data = compact('state'); ) this line. in the middle of $state and return line

Answer (score 0):

please check  controller function

```
public function getstate(Request $request) {
  $state = State::where('countryid' `=` ,request->$countryid)->get();
  return response()->json($state);
}
```

Comment: ( ‘=‘, ) This is making an error.